# Sequential array issue

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

Back end code - PHP
Front end - Angular/JavaScript

I am experimenting around with a preferential search on my website - I have users who are mapped to friends, each user can post certain content which can be "liked", my idea for the search was to count how many of the users friends have "liked" resources on the site and sort them from highest to lowest. I have the main chunk of this working (the background code) and have it returning an object that looks like:

```
{"results":
    "post":
        {"9":   {"message" : "blah9"}
        , 
        "1":    {"message" : "blah"}}
}
```

The number is the id of the post - just a side note, which I'm using to refresh something elsewhere on the site, my problem is, is when I console.log(); this onto the screen it changes to:

```
{"results":
    "post":
        {"1":   {"message" : "blah"},
        "9":    {"message" : "blah9"}}
}
```

Which makes the sorting code kind of useless, is there anyway I can stop this from happening?

```
$http.post('php/router.php', {'request' : 'search', 'page': 'Search', 'searchString': searchString}).success(function(data) {
            console.log(data.results.post);
        });
```

Comment: Properties in objects (those aren't arrays) have no defined order. If you want a defined ordering, use arrays.

Comment: add a `liked` property and can use angular `orderBy: liked`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the Javascript side of things do the sorting and totally remove the sort from your PHP.  Just have the PHP do the pagination of the set (1 to 10, 11 to 20, etc) and the Javascript can order results for you (chunks of 10 from my earlier example) for you.

Probably you'll still have some kind of sort on the PHP side if you have a ton of results to chunk up but the JS can certainly sort out each chunk that is sent to the client.